# Array.filter works only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

my problem is i have this function:

```
function filterByCheckBox(e) {
   if (e.target.checked == true) {
       const checkOption = e.target.value;
       const div = document.getElementById('peoples');
       if (devsFiltered != "") {
           const filtered = devsFiltered.filter(item => {
               for (let x = 0; x < item.programmingLanguages.length; x++) {
                   return item.programmingLanguages[x].language == checkOption;
               }
           });
           div.innerHTML = ""
           devsFiltered = filtered;
           mapUsers(filtered);
       }
   }
}
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
checkBoxes.forEach(box => {
   return box.addEventListener('change', filterByCheckBox)
})
```

Basically i'm filtering the array "devsFiltered" according to the value how comes by the checkbox, where are 3 possible selections: Java, JavaScript or Python and in the devsFiltered i have an array of informations and a sub-array called "programmingLanguages" where contains the languages to filter, so the problem is when i select the checkbox the first time, works fine and returns the array filtered, but if i try once more time when the function makes the devsFiltered.filter() he simples return an empty array.
Any ideias?

Things i verified:
The devsFiltered after the first filter isnt empty.

Comment: If you can call `filter` on `devsFiltered` then presumably it is an Array, which means you shouldn't be comparing it to an empty string. Do you mean `devsFiltered.length > 0`?

Comment: You have a `for` loop with a non-conditional `return` in it, which means it is no longer a loop.

Comment: Is your goal here to try and extract which languages have been checked, then filter some other list based on those selections? If so, seems like you just need to reduce your incoming list down to the `language` properties of each. It's hard to evaluate this code because you don't give any sample input or desired output.

Comment: @tadman thx for the observation i change it, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There's a lot of problems here, like layers of them, and I'm not sure I can solve them all in one swoop.

Comment: Where do you "un-filter" your list to get everything before filtering again?

Comment: @crashmstr sorry, i dont point in the question but the objective is to filter the list there was filtered before.Anyway, the answer below solved the problem, thanks for everyone there try to figure the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       const filtered = devsFiltered.filter(item => {
           for (let x = 0; x < item.programmingLanguages.length; x++) {
               return item.programmingLanguages[x].language == checkOption;
           }
       });
```

Your `for` loop always returns when it hits the first programming language, which means you're filtering down to programmers whose *first* programming language matches the one you've checked, rather than those who have *any* matching programming language. If you check another programming language, then you're filtering to the programmers whose first programming language matches *both* checkbox values.

Consider using `.some()` instead of a loop:

```
       const filtered = devsFiltered
          .filter(item => item.programmingLanguages
              .some(lang => lang.language == checkOption));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! solved the problem, i was stuck on this for hours.